# Aligning axis and with multiplot axis labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to both add multi-plot axis labels and align plots axis in ggplot2.

Here is an example with mtcars data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

#make some plots
c1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())
c2 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_line() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())
c3 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_path() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())
c4 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_violin() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())

#arrange and add axis
grid.arrange(
  arrangeGrob(c1,c2,ncol = 1, left = "Left Axis",bottom = "Bottom Left"),
  arrangeGrob(c3,c4,ncol = 1, left = "Middle Axis"),
  ncol = 2
)
```

[image: I want the axis aligned at the red arrows.]

I want to keep the Bottom Left axis label and align the the axis as well. The 'bottom' label will be slightly below the plot area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

```
c1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())
c2 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_line() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())
c3 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_path() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())
c4 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_violin() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())

#arrange and add axis
grid.arrange(
  arrangeGrob(c1,c2,ncol = 1, left = "Left Axis",bottom = "Bottom Left"),
  arrangeGrob(c3,c4,ncol = 1, left = "Middle Axis", bottom = " "),
  ncol = 2
)
```

[image]

## Or

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

c1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())
c2 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_line() + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + labs(x = "Bottom") 
c3 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_path() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())
c4 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_violin() + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + labs(x = " ")

library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(c1, c3, c2, c4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: The alignment problem is caused by the label "Bottom" at the bottom of the panel; if you add this label, does your solution still work?

Comment: @jared_mamrot I have revised my answer to address this.

Comment: Thank you both so much! adding a dummy label to the right bottom probably should have been my first thought... Good to know that ggarrange automatically aligns these as well. thanks so much!